# How to .limit order by DESC, then order by (:id)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, tag-cloud

This limits the tags to the top 20 with the highest tag count:

**tag.rb**

```
scope :top_20, -> {
  where("taggings_count != 0").order("taggings_count DESC").limit(3)
}
```

I want to then order those 20 according to their `:id` instead of by their tagging_count

**application_controller**

```
before_action :tag_cloud
def tag_cloud
  @tags = Tag.all.top_20.order(:id)
end
```

`.order(:id)` unfortunately doesn't work. They are still showing in descending order by count.

**_tags.html.erb**

```
<% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag), :class => css_class %>
<% end %>
```

Please let me know if you need further **code or explanation** to help you help me :-]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query will only take the first `order` into consideration. You can override it with [reorder](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/reorder) however this won't work in your case since it will override the `order("taggings_count DESC")`.

What works for you is [sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort):

`@tags = Tag.all.top_20.sort{ |x,y| x.id <=> y.id }`

Comment: Thank you so much @Abm been at this for awhile :)

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com You were looking for this one.. Damn!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this with pure SQL instead of using Ruby `sort`, you have to do it with a subquery:

```
Tag.from(Tag.top_20, :tags).order(:id)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from

Answer (score 1):

I would rather rewrite this scope like so:

```
from(
  where.not(taggings_count: 0)
     .order(taggings_count: :desc)
     .limit(20)
        .as(table_name)
)
```

What this does is modify a `FROM`-clause to fetch results not from `'tags'` table, but from a temporary result set (fetched in a **subquery**) aliased to have the same name (`table_name` returns just that) to fool ActiveRecord into thinking we're querying the same source. You can apply any operations on top as if it was a whole table.

As for the `as`-method, that doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere... it comes from Arel, the SQL AST manager used in ActiveRecord under the hood. In fact, it's delegated to the query's `Arel::SelectManager`, available on `arel` method on any `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit that one may be from Arel, I just tried it and it worked. Even so, you can give `from` the alias name as a second argument and it will work pretty much the same.

Comment: @ArupRakshit it is indeed from Arel. Delegation is in effect. A more complete form is `.arel.as(table_name)`

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear about your question, do you want to order record as desc or asc order?

Write an scopes as following

```
scope :order_id_asc, -> { order('id ASC') }
scope :order_id_desc, -> { order('id DESC') }
```

And re-write your code as following, with calling any one of scopes

```
def tag_cloud
    @tags = Tag.top_20.order_id_asc
end
```